# Ansible : Not able to switch user from remote machine

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible. Trying to copy some files to remote machine.
I am able to copy to remote server's tmp folder, but not able to copy to a particular users folder.

I think it is possible if we can switch to that particular user. But I am not able to do so using playbook.

Please help me on this.

Regards,
KP

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue. The user which you use to connect to the host does not have permissions to write to that other users folder.

If you have access to that users account (e.g. your ssh key is accepted) you can simply define the user per task through `remote_user`:

```
- copy: src=...
        dest=...
  remote_user: <SET_OWNER_HERE>
```

If you do not have access, you can use the `sudo` flag to execute a task with `root` permissions. But make sure you set the permissions correctly or the user might not be able to read/write those files:

```
- copy: src=...
        dest=...
        owner=<SET_OWNER_HERE>
        group=<SET_GROUP_HERE>
        mode=0644
  sudo: yes
```

Also, you can define the username as which the sudo command is executed with `sudo_user`:

```
- copy: src=...
        dest=...
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: <SET_OWNER_HERE>
```

If `sudo` requires a password from you, you have to provide it or the task will hang forever without any error message.

You can define this globally in the [`ansible.cfg`](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#ask-sudo-pass):

```
ask_sudo_pass=True
```

Or pass the option when you call your playbook:

```
ansible-playbook ... --ask-sudo-pass
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the second option but the play book got stuck at file copy task.

Comment: That probably means the task is stuck at a sudo password prompt. If sudo requires the password from you, you can configure Ansible to ask it from you during play: Global setting: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#ask-sudo-pass or pass `--ask-sudo-pass` on command line. I updated the answer to include this info.

Comment: ---
- hosts: test
  tasks:
  - name: Copy Files
    copy: src=/local_user/test.sh dest=/remote/location/another/user(kp)/bin/ owner=kp group=kp mode=0644
    sudo: yes                                                                                                command I used is ansible-playbook -i hosts playbooks/commands.yml --user sshuser --ask-pass --ask-sudo-pass   when su password asked I gave the password used to log onto kp user in the remote machine. Is that correct?

Comment: Hard to read without formatting, but it looks OK to me. Does it work?

Comment: Still taking lots of time..getting stuck at copy files.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. You can try to pass `-vvvv` and see if that verbose output tells you anything about the problem. Also, it might be there is a general issue, I found this in the Ansible Bug tracker: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9544